# Installing JVM in a device with ARM11

Tags: java, jvm, arm

I have a hardware device with following specifications

RAM: ~200-250 MB
Speed: ~800 - 1000 MHz
Processor: cortex arm11

We have a C/C++ based SDK to develop applications for the device. Now we want to put JVM inside the device so that people can do java based development too. (Very similar to DVM inside Android OS)

I am a Java guy, but not proficient in C/C++ and Kernel level details. 
Could anyone kindly suggest me how to start the whole process or any link where I can improve my knowledge in this direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Java applications on an ARMv6 device but the overall experience (performance and api coverage wise) won't be easily similar to a desktop one.

You can use [Java SE Embedded](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javase/index.html) to run headless (non gui) applications assuming your device a VFP unit. (ARMv6/7 Linux - Headless EABI, VFP, SoftFP ABI, Little Endian1)

You can also use a third party Java virtual machine like [JamVM](http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/).

These are all easy if you already have a working arm device with a Linux kernel. In this case you can also port Android to your device easier and this will make it simpler to introduce your device to external developers, you can just say "it is an android 2.3 device". There are various pages (all somehow half baked) about porting Android and Google is your friend.

Comment: Was successful using java SE embedded, but the foot print is high. Will try JamVM.
Thanks for the response.